# Count number of "first time buyers" per month / per country in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem to compose proper mysql query to get the expected results.

I have following mysql table (shop_orders)

| order_id | email | order_date | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test-1@email.com | 2022-01-01 00:05:00 | _it |
| 2 | test-2@email.com | 2022-01-02 00:05:00 | _it |
| 3 | test-3@email.com | 2022-01-03 00:05:00 | _hu |
| 4 | test-4@email.com | 2022-02-03 00:05:00 | _hu |
| 5 | test-4@email.com | 2022-03-03 00:05:00 | _hu |
| 6 | test-5@email.com | 2022-03-03 00:05:00 | _ro |

I need to count the number of "first time purchase emails" (so if the same email is present in next month again it's not taken in to the consideration), on monthly bases per country.

So the expected result will look like this:

| month | _it | _hu | _ro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2022 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Feb 2022 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Mar 2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Currently what I have is this, since I have figured out, that I need to group by email (to show only unique "first time purchase emails"), but now I don't know how to sum per country and on monthly bases

```
SELECT 
    order_id, status, email, country, order_date
FROM
    pinkpanda.shop_orders
WHERE
        AND deleted = 'false'
        AND shipping_date <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        AND status = 'sent'
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY order_id ASC;
```

If you have any additional questions, please let me know and I will provide
Thank you!

Comment: Same email can be in two different countries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must first obtain unique emails and pick the oldest one by using `WITH cte` or a subquery, and then

We employ conditional aggregation with `sum()`:

```
with cte as (
  select email, min(order_date) as order_date, max(country) as country
  from shop_orders
  group by email
)
select date_format(order_date, '%b %Y') as month, 
       sum(case when country = '_it' then 1 else 0 end) as _it,
       sum(case when country = '_hu' then 1 else 0 end) as _hu,
       sum(case when country = '_ro' then 1 else 0 end) as _ro
from cte
group by date_format(order_date, '%b %Y')
```

Or using `count()` :

```
with cte as (
  select email, min(order_date) as order_date, max(country) as country
  from shop_orders
  group by email
)
select date_format(order_date, '%b %Y') as month, 
       count(case when country = '_it' then 1 end) as _it,
       count(case when country = '_hu' then 1 end) as _hu,
       count(case when country = '_ro' then 1 end) as _ro
from cte
group by date_format(order_date, '%b %Y')
```

For the oldest MySQL versions, here is a working solution :

```
select date_format(order_date, '%b %Y') as month, 
       sum(case when country = '_it' then 1 else 0 end) as _it,
       sum(case when country = '_hu' then 1 else 0 end) as _hu,
       sum (case when country = '_ro' then 1 else 0 end) as _ro
from (
  select email, min(order_date) as order_date, max(country) as country
  from shop_orders
  group by email
) as cte
group by date_format(order_date, '%b %Y')
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CPLL41PC)

Comment: Won't this sum all emails?
Check Mar 2022 in example.. test-4@email.com must NOT be calculated again, since it was already calculated(sum) in FEB 2022

Comment: I fixed it, can you check my update

Comment: I need to do a little reformatting, since we are using mysql 5.6 and with is not valid on this position :) give me few minutes :)